# Functions for Buttons

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to figure out how to do this thing for an android app.
So I made an array of buttons

```
Button btn[][] = new Button[10][10];
```

How do I make it so that once I click a button that it, for instance, turns a different color?
I have had trouble making it because I can create the array, and it looks nice, but how do I assign different functions for individual buttons? Are buttons in the array already labeled and can I use individual ones? Thanks.

Comment: `So I made an array of buttons` Anytime you are making an array of View's you should be wondering if an AdapterView (i.e. [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)) would be a better option. And almost always the answer is yes.

Comment: Isn't this an array of button arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you would like to make a view change a different color based on the user actions, you should use a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

Here is a very simple example of a state list drawable which you would use to trigger only off whether the user had pressed the view or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/brown" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/brown_selected" />
</selector>
```

You would then set this on the view with the following attribute to the view in xml

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

This though, will only be changed while the user is pressing the button. If you would like it to permenantly change color, use a [on click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).  For example if you would like to change the background color to white:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    /**
     * Handle a user clicking on the view v
     * @param v the view the user clicked on. In this case the button
     */
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        // Set the background color to white
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh silly me I forgot all about onClickListeners! Thanks a million.